# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register Gatsby realated

Tags: gatsby, favicon

As I cannot comment because of my low reputation I have added this question so I can set my own answer. I hope this can solve issues for other developers.

I got this error: `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register Gatsby realated`
I am working with Gatsbyjs. The error appears when trying to run develop. Basically on this case it was because I have added the plugin: "gatsby-plugin-manifest" later on.
I believe the problem was because some dependencies used by this plugin-manifest are also used by this another plugin: "gatsby-plugin-sharp". They both can set the favicon to the webpage.
So my solution was:

- Reinstall the plugin "gatsby-plugin-sharp" just by running -> `npm install --save gatsby-plugin-sharp`

By doing this, now I was able to run `npm run develop`.

**Why posting about this**
Basically we know that a particular issue may be related to many things. This is why I posted this solution for this particular problem. Some other solutions tell about remove the node_modules folder and run again `npm install` to install all the modules quoted in package.json but in my case I wanted to try another solution because **some of the plugin I am using I don't need them to get updated**

Well hope this help others.

Answer (score 6):

Just for the sake of my own programming. I will reply myself.

In deed this issue is caused for the libvips 8.9.0+ which is installed globally, at least under MacOS.
So the solution that worked for me is the same as stated in [this github issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/21757)

Solution run the following command inside of the gatsby app folder:

```
rm -rf node_modules && SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS=true yarn
```

Note: this command will remove the folder node_modules, then, it will set the sharp global lib installed as ignored for this installation and it will run yarn.

After doing that you should be able to run:

```
yarn start
```

Good luck! May the force be with Us.